# String conversion discrepancy

Tags: excel, string, numbers, double, string-conversion

I'm importing several sheets of data to another workbook and wanted a simple way of converting the strings that are numbers into numbers. So I found this code that did exactly what I wanted https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/8/21/convert-numbers-stored-as-text

It ran fast and smoothly which was very appreciated, but when I started to work with the data I noticed a discrepancy. I found that two cells had converted into two completely different numbers. As of writing these are the only two I have found, but it is quite worrying if there could be more. An example is the string "1,225" became -611779. (Yes I'm using decimal commas)

For some reason it decided that these two "strings" of numbers was something completely different. Yet, the same numbers, in another sheet, had been correctly converted.

My question now is: is there some reason that these two (and perhaps more cells) could have caused the script to completely fail in converting these numbers correctly. Or is the code flawed?

```
Sub CleanData(sRange As Range)

'PURPOSE:Clean up selected data by trimming spaces, converting dates,
'and converting numbers to appropriate formats from text format
'AUTHOR: Ejaz Ahmed (www.StrugglingToExcel.Wordpress.com)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim MessageAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim EachRange As Range
Dim TempArray As Variant
Dim rw As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim ChangeCase As Boolean
Dim ChangeCaseOption As VbStrConv
Dim rng As Range

'User Preferences
  ChangeCaseOption = vbProperCase
  ChangeCase = False

'Set rng = Application.Selection
Set rng = sRange

'Warn user if Range has Formulas
  If RangeHasFormulas(rng) Then
    MessageAnswer = MsgBox("Some of the cells contain formulas. " _
      & "Would you like to proceed and overwrite formulas with values?", _
      vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Formulas Found")
    If MessageAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  End If

'Loop through each separate area the selected range may have
  For Each EachRange In rng.Areas
    TempArray = EachRange.Value2
      If IsArray(TempArray) Then
        For rw = LBound(TempArray, 1) To UBound(TempArray, 1)
          For col = LBound(TempArray, 2) To UBound(TempArray, 2)
            'Check if value is a date
              If IsDate(TempArray(rw, col)) Then
                TempArray(rw, col) = CDate(TempArray(rw, col))

            'Check if value is a number
              ElseIf IsNumeric(TempArray(rw, col)) Then
                TempArray(rw, col) = CDbl(TempArray(rw, col))

            'Otherwise value is Text. Let's Trim it! (Remove any extraneous spaces)
              Else
                TempArray(rw, col) = Application.Trim(TempArray(rw, col))

                'Change Case if the user wants to
                  If ChangeCase Then
                    TempArray(rw, col) = StrConv( _
                    TempArray(rw, col), ChangeCaseOption)
                  End If
              End If
          Next col
        Next rw
      Else
        'Handle with Single Cell selected areas
          If IsDate(TempArray) Then 'If Date
            TempArray = CDate(TempArray)
          ElseIf IsNumeric(TempArray) Then 'If Number
            TempArray = CDbl(TempArray)
          Else 'Is Text
            TempArray = Application.Trim(TempArray)
              'Handle case formatting (if necessary)
                If ChangeCase Then
                  TempArray = StrConv(TempArray, ChangeCaseOption)
                End If
          End If
      End If

    EachRange.Value2 = TempArray

  Next EachRange

'Code Ran Succesfully!
'MsgBox "Your data cleanse was successful!", vbInformation, "All Done!"

End Sub

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function RangeHasFormulas(ByRef rng As Range) As Boolean

'PURPOSE: Determine if given range has any formulas in it
'AUTHOR: Ejaz Ahmed (www.StrugglingToExcel.Wordpress.com)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim TempVar As Variant

TempVar = rng.HasFormula

'Test Range
  If IsNull(TempVar) Then
    'Some of cells have fromulas
      RangeHasFormulas = True
  Else
    If TempVar = True Then
      'All cells have formulas
        RangeHasFormulas = True
    Else
      'None of cells have formulas
        RangeHasFormulas = False
    End If
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: I can't see any way that code could produce that result, even with a different decimal separator. Did you have any other workbooks open at the time (especially ones with userforms), or any other code in the workbook?

Comment: @Rory I tried closing all other excel workbooks and even restarting the computer but none of it helped me in anyway. The only other code in the workbook is the one that imports the data from the other workbook, but that can't be the problem because I did try comment out the conversion code and then I do get the correct values (but in string form). So I'm still nowhere closer to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have any userforms in any open workbooks? If the same code worked on the same number string elsewhere, the problem has to lie elsewhere really.

Comment: @Rory No i don't have any userforms in any of my workbooks. I did try to remove all formatting from my datasource, and it actually helped in one case where I got wrong numbers, but not in all places :S

Comment: The problem is that the string `1,225`, when not enclosed in quotes is sometimes being interpreted as a date.  Specifically `1 Jan 225`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that code is that the VBA `IsDate` function will use, among other things, a comma as a delimiter.  So `1,225` gets considered to be the date `1-Jan-225`.  Since that is not a legitimate Excel value, it gets converted to a negative number (prior to `1-Jan-1900`).

If all you are dealing is converting numbers stored as strings to real numbers, then you can use:

```
Option Explicit
Sub colaTextToNumbers()
    Dim R As Range

'Can be set in many different ways
Set R = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'for column A

'Set R = Selection
'Set R = whatever

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With R
    .EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General" 'or could limit this just to R, not entire column
    .Value = .Value
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I imagined it had something to do with it. I removed the If-statement that handled dates and I got it to work. For the time being I don't need to handle dates in my formulas so I think I'll leave at that. 

I tried your code but didn't get it to work because ".NumberFormat" wouldn't work on a range.

Comment: @VinnieNovido `.NumberFormat` certainly does work on a range.  There may be something about your data, or how you tried implementing my solution, that is messing things up.

Comment: @RonResenfeld I changed the variable R as an input variable and sent the range of my sheet. However all I get is Error 1004, The property NumberFormat cannot be applied for the class Range.

Comment: @VinnieNovido without seeing your implementation, it is hard to tell what the problem is. However numberformat is a property of the range object.